# Effect of turbulent flow on flight

Tags: aircraft-performance, wing, turbulence, laminar-flow

What effect does turbulent flow (let’s say over a wing) have on flight?

Could I say it reduces flight performance like lift, increase drag?

Comment: Performance of? Engines? Structure? Max flight speed? On board comfort? Cabin crew? Captain? Overhead locker? 

Comment: Hi, I meant like drag, lift, fuel consumption

Comment: Ok. Next question: Do you mean turbolent like in "turbolent boundary layer" or like in "gusts"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll need to talk about two kinds of turbulence...

When the pilot says 'we are expecting some turbulence' and you feel the aircraft bouncing around somewhat violently -- that turbulence is caused by non-uniform winds (often with a vertical component) that the aircraft is flying through.  Since they are non-uniform (localized), the aircraft encounters them as an unsteady event -- an updraft for a moment - and then gone.  These unsteady, non-uniform winds cause the local angle of attack on the aircraft to change -- causing changes in the aerodynamic forces that then bump and shake the aircraft around.

Fortunately, these events are relatively quick.  They do not effect the aircraft's fuel consumption, maximum speed, or rate of climb in any significant way.  However, the aircraft structure must be designed for gusts and turbulence.  It is a contribution to the safety factors that go into structural design of the aircraft -- that in turn determines how much the structure weighs.  So, in a sense -- if you could guarantee no turbulence, you could make a lighter aircraft that would burn less fuel, etc.  It would also break the first time it encountered a gust.

The other kind of turbulence is what we mean when we discuss whether a flow is laminar or turbulent.  Laminar flow is parallel, uniform, smooth flow in a boundary layer around an aircraft.  Turbulent flow is chaotic flow with tiny eddies of random motion in the boundary layer of an aircraft.

A turbulent flow will have a higher skin friction coefficient and will have more drag on the same surface area than a laminar flow would have.

However, that turbulent flow will tend to stay attached a little more than a laminar flow would in the same situation.  So, if the local drag is dominated by separation (not skin friction), a turbulent flow may have less drag than a laminar flow.

The latter is why golf balls have dimples.  The dimples encourage transition to turbulence (they 'trip' the boundary layer).  This delays separation and reduces the drag on the golf ball -- skin friction drag goes up, but the separation drag goes down more than enough to counter that.

This delay in separation will also tend to allow turbulent airfoils to reach a higher CLmax than the same airfoil in a laminar flow.

Most aircraft fly mainly in turbulent flow.  We design them expecting turbulent flow, so we don't think of it as reducing flight performance -- as we planned for it from the start.

High performance sailplanes are able to take advantage of significant laminar flow.  Their performance is negatively affected when dead bugs accumulate on the leading edge of the wing -- this can cause the boundary layer to trip and for the flow characteristics to change.  Some aggressive laminar flow airfoils have even demonstrated being sensitive to rain.